# How to reuse the code in same script in perl

Tags: perl

How to reuse code in the same script in Perl? Either we need to use `require` or `use`. Or, is there any other method/thing?

Note: the script that I'm using is not a function.

Comment: You need to *make* it into a function and take a look at [`Exporter`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter)

Comment: If you want to reuse code in *the same* script, you could just make it a function (called sub) and call it. Or do you want to reuse code throughout several scripts? Either way -1. Googling your exact question yields answers for both.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use a script file at two places of another script, or that you want to reuse logic *within* the script file?

Comment: i want to reuse the logic with in the script. I don't want to use functions.I need to know is there any alternative method

Comment: @VamsiKrishna, you should realize that you did nothing more than simply repeat your original *vague* phrase, when I asked for a clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to "reuse" or repeat code without using subs

eval takes a string and runs it as perl.  See the entry in perldoc perlfunc

using a code reference takes an unnamed function and takes a reference to it.  This can then be run as shown.

AUTOLOAD is a bit more crazy.  This analyses the functions you call and looks for patterns in the function name and then makes it behave as if there was a real function with this name

There are loads of other ways of doing code "reuse" in perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use warnings;
use strict;


#example : eval
my $x="print qq(cheese\n)";

eval "$x";

#example : code reference
my $code=sub { my $param=shift; print qq(hairy $param\n); };

$code->("goats");

#example : AUTOLOAD

no strict 'subs';
use vars qw/$AUTOLOAD/;
sub AUTOLOAD {
  my $full=$AUTOLOAD;
  if ($full =~ /panda_(\d)/ ) {
    print "panda " x $1;
    print "\n";
  }
}

panda_3();
panda_6();
```